# OpenGL: finding out vertex structure in other apps using OpenGL

Tags: opengl, 3d

Suppose you have a third party program on your desktop that uses OpenGL (the fixed pipeline version, <2.0), for example, Street View in Google Maps. Is there a way to find out more about what that app is actually rendering in OpenGL? In particular, I'm interested in the vertices that are used for drawing -- how many are there, and where they are.

I could imagine something existing like a hacked/modified OpenGL driver or similar that could show you the actual vertices overlaid as dots on the display, but can't find any such thing.

Comment: [gDEBugger](http://www.gremedy.com/products.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[gDEBugger](http://www.gremedy.com/) can do that for standalone OpenGL applications.

For the record:

There is also [WebGL inspector](http://benvanik.github.com/WebGL-Inspector/) for WebGL.

There is also a variety of [OpenGL ES tools for mobile platforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432721/opengl-es-2-0-debugging) if that is of use, but typically these do not record enough information to completely reconstruct a scene for debugging.

Comment: You've beat me to that one :)

Comment: Thanks very much, no idea how I missed those when first searching the web!