# Are there any good OpenGL ES 2.0 Debuggers like gDebugger used to be?

Tags: debugging, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I tried using gDebugger but apparently it no longer supports OpenGL ES.  I saw a question similar to this one, but it was over a year old, so I thought maybe things had changed by now.  Any suggestions?

Comment: What type of platform are you developing for? Android, iOS, something else?

Comment: Look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432721/opengl-es-2-0-debugging

Comment: Android in the long run, but for now I'm learning it using the PowerVR SDK on the desktop.  Since it emulates OpenGL ES 2.0 on the desktop I don't have to worry about Android weirdness confusing my learning of OpenGL.

Comment: I'm aware of PVRTrace but I was hoping for something more like gDebugger that could attach to a running process.